# VLC doesn't open through terminal or GUI

Tags: command-line, apt, snap, vlc

I installed VLC through terminal but it shows:

```
bash: /snap/bin/vlc: No such file or directory
```

I also tried:

```
which vlc
```

and it showed:

```
/usr/bin/vlc
```

When I try to run it through `sudo su`, it shows this error:

```
VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry.
If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports
you can use vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and
cannot be run by non-trusted users first).
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

I tried using the snap VLC package, which I installed using the terminal, but I couldn't navigate to my `Downloads` folder. I could only navigate in the "computer" folder, which consists of `/bin`, `/usr`, `/var`, etc. I was able to play the items of the folder I wanted by dragging and dropping.

I'm also only able to open VLC through the terminal. Opening it through the start menu doesn't do anything.

I'm using Zorin OS 16, which is based on Ubuntu 20.04, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You may also want to set up an alias. If you type `gedit ~/.bash_aliases` you will see an editor with a file in it. The file may or may not be blank. At the bottom, add `alias vlc=/usr/bin/vlc`. Be sure not to change anything else. Now, when you type `vlc`, it will run `/usr/bin/vlc`. You can do this with any command, or set of commands, that you use often, to shorten the amount of characters that need typed. In case that doesn't work in zorin, add to `~/.bashrc`, but try `~/.bash_aliases` first.

Comment: tysm this worked like a charm! how do i mark this as answer?

Comment: Tysm is mark enough. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should run

```
$ /usr/bin/vlc
```

As for why executing `vlc` looks for `/snap/bin/vlc`, I wouldn't know.
If you had a snap for vlc installed, I guess it should have worked as well.

Perhaps you have an `alias` set in your `~/.bashrc` or elsewhere.
If you find such an alias, and remove it, you could probably start running `vlc` without the need for prepending the full path.

**EDIT**

To remove the difficulty, you could check if you actually have any file or soft link `/snap/bin/vlc`.
Check with

```
$ type vlc
$ ls -al /snap/bin/vlc
```

Also, you could setup your own `alias vlc=/usr/bin/vlc` in `~/.bashrc`.
If that is read after the presumed other alias, you would be ok.

Comment: this fix worked thanks! im new to ubuntu could you guide me through removing this alias? i tried opening .bashrc in terminal using sudo it still says permission denied...

Comment: @HaadeeBinHafees Have you removed the snap VLC before installing the deb version?

Comment: @HaadeeBinHafees - Please see updated answer. 
Notes:
1) Instead of narrating what you did ("i tried opening .bashrc in terminal using sudo"), post the exact command.
2) Instead of narrating what you obtained ("it still says permission denied"), post the exact and complete output.
3) If this solved your problem, please accept the answer. Whether you had installed/removed the snap, etc., is a separate issue.

Comment: i typed `~/.bashrc ` and its output was `bash: /home/zorin16/.bashrc: Permission denied
`
i then tried going into sudo su and typed `~/.bashrc `  again and its output was `bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
`
i realise my problem was not using gedit. i was confused as i couldnt find the file in my 'computer' folder...

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes i removed snap vlc before installing deb version which i assume is the apt-install version?

Comment: @HaadeeBinHafees - Please see updated answer.

Comment: thx for ur updated answer @Nate T already answered this before my referring me to setting the vlc alias steps. it would be better if you include steps like using gedit to open bashrc

Answer (score 4):

Originally posted as [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365509/vlc-doesnt-open-through-terminal-or-gui#comment2344105_1365509) by [Nate T](https://askubuntu.com/users/1164434/nate-t):

> You may also want to set up an alias, as well.
>
> If you type `gedit ~/.bash_aliases`, you will see an editor with a file in it. The file may or may not be blank.
>
> At the bottom (or the top if the file is empty), add the following:
>
> ```bsh
> alias vlc=/usr/bin/vlc
> ```
>
> Be sure not to change anything else. Now, when you type `vlc` in the terminal, it will run the command `/usr/bin/vlc`.
>
> You can do this with any command, or set of commands that you use often, to shorten the amount of characters that need typed.
>
> In case this doesn't work in your current environment (and the file you edited earlier was blank), run the following command:
>
> ```bsh
> printf '\n\nif [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then\n    source ~/.bash_aliases\n fi\n\n' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> This will add the needed code to the proper file, in order to source the `.bash_aliases` file.
>
> You can also add the line to `~/.bashrc`, but save this option to be used only as a last resort, in case you cannot get it to work using `~/.bash_aliases`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had VLC installed as snap, removed it, and then re-installed it via `apt(-get)`, your error means that the location table still uses an old entry. That issue was raised and solved [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1459095/why-does-bash-give-no-such-file-or-directory-for-a-program-thats-in-my-path)

You can confirm this by typing:

```shell
type vlc
```

and it may print something like `vlc is hashed (/snap/bin/vlc)`. So, all you should have to do is type this in the terminal once:

```shell
hash vlc
```

Note that this will produce no output message. After that, run `vlc` as normal and it should work.